# I can't figure out why my AWS Lambda function is being invoked twice

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-event-bridge

I've looked everywhere, trying to figure out what's wrong, but I cannot find a solution. Hopefully, you all can help.

I am an absolute noob regarding AWS Lambda and am still learning to code through JS. I've got my code to test and run properly, but I'm finding that when the function runs as scheduled using the cron formula, it runs once at 7:15 am EST (12:15 pm UTC) as coded but then runs again precisely 5 hours later. I think it's a time zone error, but I am unsure if that is true. There are no timeouts, and each run has a different run ID.

I have looked through the logs, and there don't seem to be any errors or timeouts. I've also looked at the invocations of the EventBridge trigger, and it seems only to be triggering once. My code has no indication of time within it or to be started at anytime, so it's not that either.

Here is the cron formula used on my EventBridge trigger: `15 12 ? * 2 *`

I'm really lost and would like any possible help or to be pointed in the right direction!!

Comment: Are you logging the event that the Lambda function receives? Does it offer any clues?

Comment: That cron schedule should only be running once a week, at 12:15 UTC on Mondays. I suggest looking in EventBridge to make sure you don't have another cron schedule defined. And also logging the `event` object as the first thing you do in your Lambda handler. The contents of the `event` object may indicate what is triggering it the 2nd time.

Comment: @jarmod I haven't logged it because I thought I could trust the Cloudwatch logs on when an error occurs. Cloudwatch doesn't indicate a failure on launch. The entire script basically makes an API call, takes the text document, parses it, then uploads into Airtable. With each run, all of the files are being completed so it's not like it is erroring/timing out.

Comment: I'd log the event to CloudWatch Logs (trivial to do) and then compare events after the fact.

Comment: @MarkB I don't have any other EventBridge triggers at all, this is my first ever AWS Lambda function. And also, all of the code is within a function export `export const handler = async (event) => {` if that's what you mean... excuse my lack of knowledge :(

Comment: @jarmod Any thoughts/videos on where/how I could do this? This is all so new to me and was kind of thrown into AWS as a last result lol

Comment: Ensure the Lambda function has at least the minimal permissions needed for logging (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html#permissions-executionrole-console)). It needs at least AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole. Then simply `console.log(event)` in your Lambda function, invoke the function, then review CloudWatch Logs for the function.

Comment: @jarmod I started a CloudTrail trail for my function. When looking at the CloudTrail Event history, I actually found two separate CreateLogStream records both corresponding with the times that my function was invoked.

Would the CreateLogStream show me what I'm looking for? I've looked through both of them and don't really have an idea of what it is I'm looking for.

Comment: You don't need CloudTrail, just CloudWatch Logs, though perhaps CloudTrail includes the event (I don't know). Assuming the function has permission to log, a simple `console.log(event)` at the start of the handler function will log the value of the passed event parameter (the event that triggered the Lambda function). You will [find](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html) the logs in CloudWatch Logs.